# Where can I ask questions about RoundCube?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am trying to find a way to set a profile picture in [Roundcube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundcube). The developer who sold that service to me sent me to Stack Exchange to find an answer.

I was told:

> "*This question is only applicable to one specific site on the Stack Exchange network. It is not currently accepting answers.*
>
> *Your question is only applicable to one specific site on the network, and should have been posted on that site's meta. Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should be about policies or features that relate to multiple sites on the network or the software that drives it, within the scope in the help center. If this question does relate to multiple sites in our network, please edit it to clarify why.
> Closed 4 days ago.*"

Fine, I understand the point. But I don't know which specific site on the network my question applies to. Can you please provide a link? I will gladly go there to ask the question.

---

[The answer I did find](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95030/how-to-set-a-profile-picture-in-roundcube-webmail) was "*use [Google+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google%2B)*", which I know is no longer an active service.

I responded: "Google+ is not an answer, I should be able to downvote so your quality control team can identify outdated answers."

To which a member of the community told me:
"*It's an answer for the date it was posted at. Which is about 5 years ago.*"

OK. True, but I did not ask the question 5 years ago. Why is my question answered with that suggestion now?

If your community wants to be welcoming to newbies you should answer the actual concerns they are expressing rather than providing technically correct but unhelpful answers.

Links for context:

- Here is my question about how the non-answer cannot be the answer (now deleted):
  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385166/https-webmasters-stackexchange-com-questions-95030-how-to-set-a-profile-pictur?noredirect=1#comment1284784_385166
- And here is my toxic question about the Stack Exchange rules (now deleted):
  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385138/the-restriction-that-i-must-earn-credits-to-comment-is-stupid?noredirect=1#comment1284512_385138

I did not ask for Google+ as an answer. Why should I word the search query to rule out Google+? I didn't say anything about Google+. The recommended answer provided by the not a forum provided that response.

Comment: Looks like that profile images are not possible: https://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php/topic,24758.msg67525.html#msg67525

Comment: Please bear in mind that questions on any SE site should be self-contained. What kind of software is RoundCube? Are you an end-user, developer, service administrator, webmaster...? As the linked questions are now deleted, if they are relevant add the relevant parts direclty into the question body.

Comment: Related: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691)

Answer (score 11):

As per the comments, your question on setting a profile picture in Roundcube can be answered on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

The reason your flag on the existing answer was denied was because it used to be a valid answer, and we don't delete answers (or questions) that become outdated. That it is no longer helpful can be added in a comment (and will be appreciated!).

The fact we come across as unwelcoming to new users is known. This is, I believe, mostly due to new users being too impatient to get to know the concept behind and the rules of our website (among which is the important difference with many other sites that a certain user you seem to have met already so clearly points out: we are not a forum). They are however clearly pointed to, and available to everyone.

A second reason is that, since most users here spend their free time creating a huge database of knowledge, they won't take the time to write extensive comments, but being dry and to-the-point they might come across as rude or unhelpful. This is not intentional (and if it is objectively rude, you can always flag it).

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to find a way to set a profile pic in Roundcube. The developer who sold that service to me sent me to Stack Exchange to find an answer.

That seems a little disingenuous on their part - especially if they sent you to meta. This is less an answer to 'where' than 'how. Checking what's [on topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to a site is *essential* for successful posting here, and that's in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) of every site. That said, fobbing off tech support to SE is... kinda dodgy.

> The answer I did find was "use Google+", which I know is no longer an active service.

Ah, you got half way.

> I responded: "Google+ is not an answer, I should be able to downvote so your quality control team can identify outdated answers."

Users with experience *are* quality control.

Now for the *rest* of the way?

It’s perfectly fine to ask a follow-up question, and point out you've *seen* the other question *and* that the current answer no longer works. If it’s a good enough question with an answer, someone closing the *other* question as a duplicate to this would be a appropriate outcome.

Something along the lines of

> How do I set a profile picture in Roundcube without the use of Google+?

and

> I'd like to set a custom profile picture next to my email in Roundcube - this happens with gmail accounts, and [previously you could use G+ with your own email](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95030/how-to-set-a-profile-picture-in-roundcube-webmail) to set a custom profile. How would I do it now?

Some polish is needed; is this profile picture for senders or receivers and so on, and I'd add some screenshots.

*But* this shows you looked at the other post *and* the instructions no longer work.

> If your community wants to be welcoming to newbies you should answer the actual concerns they are expressing rather than providing technically correct but unhelpful answers.

We're humans and volunteers, and the tone of the linked deleted posts seem rather demanding. We're happy to help, *but* sometimes it’s nice to be met halfway.